# Flutter how to force font size datetime picker flutter?

Tags: flutter, datetimepicker

I'm working on a project and meet this problem, with the device which is modified font of iPhone system in **Setting => General => Accessibility => Larger Text** is **ON**, I worked around and find a way to fix font size with the code below:

```
new MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return MediaQuery(
       data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
       child: //element go here
    )
  }
)
```

This way is worked fine with common TextView and pop-up but I'm using [flutter_datetime_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker)

I read the documentation and still not find out how to fix font of DateTime picker when the pop-up shows up, How can I solve this problem, thank you, here is a picture to demonstrate it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there....
I had the same issue too. I tried so much time and found out the solution.

The below builder is the parameter of "showDatePicker".

```
builder: (context, child) {
         return MediaQuery(
                data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1),
                child: Theme(......)
         )
}
```

Just wrap the theme with MediaQuery. That's all. It works smoothly for me.

Comment: Yah it seems that Flutter has fixed this issue, it will automatically scaled down the calendar size itself without any custom configuarations

Comment: I don't think so, without configure flutter won't actually do it. I had the same situation, I need to force it. If you find the answer right please check it. Thanks